# How to retrieve <finalName> value from POM?

Tags: java, spring, maven, pom.xml

I manually set the  tag value in my pom.xml before I packaged my Spring web app to .war and then I manually deploy my .war file on JBOSS.

I have an test.html file in webapp folder which is sending an POST request to test if @RequestMapping methods inside my controller class are working as expected or not. I want to store the value of  tag in the JavaScript variable (in test.html).

How can I fetch the value from pom.xml and store in the JavaScript variable?

Comment: This is a bit unclear. How are you building your WAR for multiple environments? Through profiles? What end result are you looking for? Do you want the `qa`, or `test` to be in the final `test.html`?

Comment: I meant, if I wanted to deploy my war in QA then I am changing the finalName to MyApp-qa before packaging and similarly, for Dev I am changing the finalName to MyApp-dev. And I'm deploying the .war on JBOSS.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: @RomanC Hope it is clear to you now, let me know if you have any suggestions.

Comment: @Jammy It's not clear for me.

Answer (score 1):

Make a filtered property resource file that has ${finalName} in it, and then read that in from your classpath.

```
src/main/resources/config.properties:

finalName=${propContainingFinalName}

    <build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>config.properties</include>
            </includes>
            <filtering>true</filtering>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</build>
```

Comment: Thanks, I have one question, I can get it from JAVA but how could I get it inside the .html file (in JavaScript). My app in RESTful webapp in Spring.